# Cannot figure out bundler error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, bundler

So I use vagrant as a virtual environment as I program in windows and whenever I try to bundle install I get an error like this:

```
`Gem::FilePermissionError: You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/wrappers directory.
An error occurred while installing rake (11.2.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '11.2.2'` succeeds before bundling.`
```

I then tried to do `gem install rake` this came up:

```
`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3 directory.`
```

I thought that `sudo gem install rake` might work but then I still can't successfully bundle. Please help this is destroying my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have permission over your `gems` folder, try a very loose config, since it is a local virtual machine:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3
```

This config is unsafe, but most likely will solve your problem.

Comment: This works. Thanks so much I couldn't seem to find the solution anywhere previously.